# Macro add the same superscript

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Imagine I have many expression of the form `\phi_{i0}^A`, `\phi_{i1}^A`, etc.

I want to create a macro such that `^A` is appended automatically and I don't have to type it in, e.g. `\phispecial_{i0}` would produce the same result.

So far I've tried `\DeclareMathOperator{\phispecial}*{\phi^A}` but that produces misaligned results. Do I have to use `\newcommand` instead?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) `\newcommand\phiA{\phi^A}` would be enough, no need to tell it to be an operator as it probably is not.

Comment: (1) thank you, (2) works like a charm :)

Comment: Yes, `\newcommand` would be OK for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there is no need for `\DeclareMathOperator` as this is probably not somethig that needs to behave like `\log` and friends. So

```
\newcommand\phiA{\phi^A}
```

is enough since `A_b^c = A^c_b`

Answer (score 0):

Please define like below

```
\newcommand\phiA[1][A]{\phi^A}
```

and try

Comment: Why the optional argument?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `\newcommand\phiA[1][A]{\phi^{#1}}`, so as to possibly use the optional argument?